# Command line FTPS?

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, ftps

I need to write a batch file to auto upload a backup every day. I'm restricted to Windows. Is there free software to do this?

I was looking at [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla), but the command line interface doesn't let you auto upload files, and I need to buy a license for [CuteFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CuteFTP).

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the FTPS protocol (FTP-SSL, aka FTP-Secure), correct?  Or are you just asking for FTP programs ("FTPs" plural)?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion, yes I'm looking for the FTPES protocol.

Answer (score 11):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftps) has [command-line/scripting](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting) features.

Answer (score 4):

**[curl](http://curl.haxx.se/)** supports both STARTTLS and plain old SSL, with **[`--ssl-reqd`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--ssl-reqd)** and [`--upload-file`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T--upload-file).

```
curl --ssl-reqd --upload-file backup.txz ftp://mysite/backups/
```

Answer (score 2):

Overkill is to get to sftp, but [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) is a nice toolset. Depending on your needs, you could scale the install back to only the minimum you need or scale it up and use Bash, Python, etc. instead of a batch file.

Comment: If you're a git lover, `mysysgit` also includes the ssh toolset.

Comment: SFTP != FTPS ...

Answer (score 2):

SFTP and FTPS are both encrypted in similar fashion, BUT there is a BIG difference between their deployment and use.

However, from what I can gather, you need a FTP client for both. Filezilla is a good one that users I've dealt with never complained was too hard to figure out.

To use SFTP, you need a key exchange. To use FTPS, you issue self-signed or CA certificate AND don't need to issue private keys.

Comment: This doesn't come near to answering the question

Answer (score 0):

There's an [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFTP) client available as part of the great [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) package. It may serve your needs.

Comment: Under the hood SFTP and FTPS are completely different

Comment: The question did not specify FTPS or SFTP and there was no indication that one or the other was required.